# using ckEditor to send emails, problem with images

Tags: image, email, ckeditor

I'm using the ckEditor (http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x).
my goal is to send the the text entered as an email message.

I get the contents of the editr as suggested in the docs:

var message = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

then send the message to a webmethod on the server side, and it sends ok.

**the problem is:** the images are added as an img tag, and get the local directory address, so it cannot be viewed on the recipients side.

how can I add the images to the email message?

thanks in advance!

Comment: CKEditor is not a jQuery editor

Comment: I remember there was a configuration option in FCKEditor to trip full paths, but don't know what it is in CKEditor. However, you could simply parse the content with PHP add add the base path to the url.

Comment: shouldn't I upload the images to the email message? I'm talking about images which are on the client's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a file uploader. CKFinder integrates nicely with CKEditor. Free for demo use (and open source projects I think), but about $70 for commercial use.

Comment: One more week and it would pass the one year mark... Kinda hoping for that ;)